# Where to report bug against Plone.org site

Tags: plone

I found a bug on Plone.org portal (there is totally messed up creating new release for your product), I made a proper screenshot and wanted to submit it somewhere. However, I can't find information where it should be done - is https://dev.plone.org is correct place?

If not - where I should do this?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, https://dev.plone.org/ is the correct location.

Use the [`Website` component](https://dev.plone.org/query?status=!closed&component=Website) when filing a ticket.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a mailing list.

https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/plone-website

It may help draw attention to your problem.